# Remove character from alphanumeric string and update numeric value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a column with the alphanumeric values such as A1234, 5678Q. I want to remove character from the string and want to update remaining numeric value only.

I tried using SUBSTR and creating function but it gives me just character value.

I want to remove character and update column with the numeric values e.g. A1234 becomes 1234.

Comment: Is there only one non-decimal character?

Comment: Yes only one character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is exactly one non-digit character you can use this:

```
SELECT val
     , CASE
           WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', val) > 0 THEN STUFF(val, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', val), 1, '')
           ELSE val
       END AS val_fixed
FROM (VALUES
    ('A1234'),
    ('5678Q'),
    ('12345')
) AS tests(val)
```